# Generate Data Key from vault transit secret engine

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, vault

I have a running vault server, I enabled transit secret engine and created a vault transit secret backend_key through terraform.

```
resource "vault_mount" "transit" {
  path = "transit"
  type = "transit"
}


resource "vault_transit_secret_backend_key" "transit_key" {
  backend = vault_mount.transit.path
  name    = "test-pagination-key"
  type    = "chacha20-poly1305"
}
```

I am able to see the generated backend key in vault UI
[image]

Post the creation of this key, I need to go inside key actions and select datakey and select plaintext key and hit "create datakey" to fetch the backend key in plain text format.

[image]

[image]

But i couldn't find any terraform block to fetch this information using terraform, I have to manually fetch the datakey in plaintext format.

How can I get that key through terraform??

There is an API call I can see from vault documentation, [Document](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/transit?_ga=2.111604621.887411973.1678793852-173962072.1665205948#generate-data-key)

```
sample request
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    --data @payload.json \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/transit/datakey/plaintext/my-key
```

```
sample response
{
  "data": {
    "plaintext": "dGhlIHF1aWNrIGJyb3duIGZveAo=",
    "ciphertext": "vault:v1:abcdefgh"
  }
}
```

How can I make this API call using terraform??

Kindly gimme some path to proceed forward in this issue

Comment: Would this work: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/marcofranssen/curl/latest/docs/data-sources/request?

Comment: @MarkoE, how to pass the client token in the request???

Comment: That I don't know, I was looking only at the curl request.

Comment: @MarkoE, token can be passed at provider configuration options. I just found